# expand model in backend

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer

```
    class OrdenTrabajoserializer(BaseSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Orden_trabajo
            fields = '__all__'

            expandable_fields = {
                'vehiculo': (Vehiculoserializer, { 'many': False }),
                'asesor': (Tecnicoserializer, { 'many': False }),
                'servicio_orden_registro': (Orden_registroserializer2, { 'many': True })
            }
```

when I make a request from the frontend and I want an expanded field I execute the endpoint and it correctly brings me the expanded object

unexpanded

```
   {{url...}}/

    response: 
              { 
               orden: 1,
               .
               .
               .         
               vehiculo: 32
              }
```

expanded

```
    {{url...}}/?expand=vehiculo/

    response: 
              { 
               orden: 1,
               .
               .
               .         
               vehiculo: { id: 32, color: 'blue', ...data }
              }
```

**the problem is that I want to do the same but directly in the backend**

this is the viewset, according to the information I have searched it tells me that I should put 'permit_list_expands'

but I don't know what to do to be able to use that and expand it ...

```
        class facturarOrdenV2viewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
                queryset = Orden_trabajo.objects.all()
                serializer_class = OrdenTrabajoserializer
                permit_list_expands = ['vehiculo', 'asesor', 'servicio_orden_registro']


                def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
                    orden = self.kwargs.get('orden', None)
                    ordenTrabajo = self.queryset.get(pk = orden)
                    dict_obj = model_to_dict(ordenTrabajo)
                    print(dict_obj)

                    return Response({'OK'})
```